# Problem Installing jre in Linux debian

Tags: java, linux, jre

I am trying to install JRE in Debian Linux.I tried this command and it got installed successfully,

```
apt-get install sun-java6-jre
```

after that the `/usr/lib/jvm` got deleted from me unintentionally.Now when I am trying to install it using the same command it is giving me the message that no new packages are installed as JRE is already installed.
The problem is I am not able to install the new JRE and also not able to use the previously installed as `/usr/lib/jvm` got deleted from me

Answer (score 1):

The key word here is `--reinstall`:

```
apt-get install --reinstall sun-java6-jre
```

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 120 not upgraded.
Need to get 0B/6378kB of archives.
After this operation, 0B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  sun-java6-jre
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 91852 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace sun-java6-jre 6.26-1 (using .../sun-java6-jre_6.26-1_all.deb) ...

Comment: But still its not working out for me

Answer (score 0):

Remove the installation using:

```
sudo apt-get remove sun-java6-jre
```

and then try installing again.

Comment: ar01:/usr/lib/jvm# sudo apt-get remove sun-java6-jre
sudo: unable to resolve host ar01
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  sun-java6-bin sun-java6-jre
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 120 not upgraded.
After this operation, 101MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 91253 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing sun-java6-bin ...
Removing sun-java6-jre ...
Processing triggers for menu ...

Comment: Then by running r=this command I get :ar01:/usr/lib/jvm# apt-get install sun-java6-jre
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
sun-java6-jre is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 120 not upgraded.
ar01:/usr/lib/jvm# sudo apt-get remove sun-java6-jre
sudo: unable to resolve host ar01
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 120 not upgraded.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y

Comment: .
Unpacking sun-java6-bin (from .../sun-java6-bin_6.26-1_amd64.deb) ...
sun-dlj-v1-1 license has already been accepted
Processing triggers for menu ...
Setting up sun-java6-jre (6.26-1) ...
Setting up sun-java6-bin (6.26-1) ...
Processing triggers for menu ...

Comment: But still when I execute java -version it could not execute it